# Windows 8.1 Store app MAKEPRI build errors for new project

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I just wanted to start building apps for Windows Phone but after creating a new project for Windows Phone and hitting the F5 button to run it, I get these errors:

```
1>MakePri : error 0x80073b0a: Initializing Indexer
1>MakePRI : error 0xdef00042: Invalid qualifier: Scale
```

Note this is a new project. I haven't modified anything in it. I also tried other templates and none of them ran successfully. The verbose build log was quite large but if you want to, I can post it here. I checked and the the installation of the Visual Studio  is full (SDK and everything else is installed.)

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and so far I haven't had any problem with it. The project is targeting Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280853/build-error-in-windows-phone-universal-app

Comment: @sebagomez Yes, however the OP says that he's been using a PCL but as I mentioned here, I'm having trouble building any new project (which Visual Studio itself creates) so unfortunately I don't think it applies to me.

Comment: I just pointed it out in case VS added something you didn't want... good luck with that. Re-installing is always an option :(

Comment: Yep. Thanks very much. I checked but didn't found anything.