# PRI File is invalid error when consuming MS Band SDK in Background task

Tags: c#, nuget, microsoft-band

I'm getting a MakePRI error when trying to build the **Windows project** of an 8.1 Universal app. The strange part is that **Microsoft.Band.Phone.pri** is what is throwing the error.

Actual Errors

- **Processing Resources with error: Invalid PRI File**
- **MakePRI: PRI file is invalid**

Screenshot of Error List pane
[image: screenshot of error output]

Some facts:

- I am using **v1.3.10417** which was added via **Nuget** in **VS2013**
- I am **not** calling any Band code in the Windows app
- The error occurs only when I try to Build the Windows project (or Build Solution)
- The error occurs in any configuration (ARM or x86 in debug or release)

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280853/) post suggests it is related to unused **BCL Build Components** in a PCL. I do have a background task which references the Band SDK, and the Band SDK indeed has a dependency on BCL Build components.

This prompted me to remove all Band SDK references from the background task and everything works again!

How can I add the Band SDK back to my background task without breaking the Windows/Windows Phone project?

Comment: Did you get it sorted? A bug fix release came out a few days ago that took care of user consent issues,- and maybe a few more things? Current v is Microsoft Band SDK 1.3.10518